# Add application to autostart

Tags: autostart

I've installed System Load Indicator and set 'autostart' in preferences. For some reason it doesn't load at starting system.

How to find out the name/command of this application and then I can add it to "Startup  Applications Preferences"? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Click on the Main button (top-left corner) and type Main menu and click on Main menu. There browse to where the application is and find select the application you want to find the name for and click *Properties*. The name of the application is present in the command section.
[image: Main_menu]

[image: launcher_properties]

After that, click the main button (top-left corner)  and type and click on Startup Applications. There click Add, type a name of your choice and then in the command - put the one that you copied/saw was the name of your application and click add again. And voila! Everything's done.

[image: startup_screen]

Comment: You're talking about System Monitor - standard application in ubuntu, but I'm talking about System Load Indicator - it's a indicator in panel.

Comment: Actually you're right.

Comment: Oh cool :) Glad it worked out okay :)

Comment: For Ubuntu 13.04 you can open the *StartUp* application typing it on the dash. Because there is no *MainMenu* app, and it isn't in the top right gear neither..